# Global sbteclipse plugin not found/loaded

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, sbteclipse

I am having some serious difficulty installing sbteclipse as a global plugin.  It seams like the global plugins are not being loaded.  I created the .sbt directory and added a plugins directory.  In the plugins directory I added the following build.sbt definition:

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeSnapshots

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

the above definition is in the `~/.sbt/plugins` directory.  When I search online I see plenty of sbt startups that look like the following: (notice the global plugin load and the project definition path)

[image: sbt startup example]

Now here is an example of my sbt startup and my attempt to run eclipse:

[image: my sbt startup]

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong.  I have been working on this for hours.

EDIT:

The error I get for not running sbt as superuser:

```
> mkemnetz@ubuntu:~/git/GymWebApp$ sbt
bash: /bin/sbt: Permission denied
mkemnetz@ubuntu:~/git/GymWebApp$
```

EDIT2:

```
mkemnetz@ubuntu:~/git/GymWebApp$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/mkemnetz/.sbt/plugins
[info] Set current project to default-18287a (in build file:/home/mkemnetz/git/GymWebApp/)
> eclipse
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[error] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mkemnetz/git/GymWebApp/target/streams/$global/project-descriptors/$global/out (Permission denied)
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

This is the current error I am getting.  Still not working but much improved thanks to darwin

Comment: According to info from edit 2 you need to remove target directory, that was created by superuser. sudo rm -rf /home/mkemnetz/git/GymWebApp/target . And then run 'sbt eclipse' again

Comment: @darwin can you possibly edit your old answer or write a new one with the info you gave me in the comments so I could then accept the answer.  You have been incredibly helpful.  Everything works excellently now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `build.sbt` in my `~/.sbt/plugins` dir I have `plugins.sbt` with the content like in your example. And everything works fine for me.

UPD:

The problem occurs because of you run sbt command under superuser's environment so sbt conf is not resolved properly.

Just run `sbt` under your user after removing project `target` dir.

Comment: Seems it occurs because of you run sbt under superuser. Like on screenshot.

Comment: how do i run sbt not as a superuser?  I am told that I dont have permission if i just type sbt...I added the error message to my original post.

Comment: why you don't add permissions to sbt command for your user? seems you have access to sudo

Comment: some serious progress has been made...I edited my post with the current problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt:

> resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver
>
> addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.0.0")

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [sbteclipse github](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse)

> For sbt 0.13 and up Add sbteclipse to your plugin definition file. You
>   can use either: the global file (for version 0.13 and up) at
>   ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt the project-specific file at
>   PROJECT_DIR/project/plugins.sbt

AND I want to comment on this "backward compatibility is very important!"